# Is it possible to host a React app on Github without running "build" command?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have some React apps and I checked out the steps for hosting them on Github pages but they require to run production build command so it pushes all compressed code on Github. It it possible to keep development mode files while trying to host them?

Answer (score 0):

As React App totally run's in Node Environment until it is in development mode. And once you run a build it reproduces the bundle that can be deployed to independently run without node modules.
To run react app in development mode you have to run `npm start` and that you are unable to do on github.
So answer is no. You can't run your react app in development mode on github

Comment: I guess I have to host my app somewhere else so I can keep my source code so others can be able to read it.

Comment: If its on machine which is able to perform `npm start` and starts serving you node modules, you can definitely go with machine but you can't host it on github in development mode.

Comment: Maybe I could have 2 versions. I push one project as I normally do just the source code nothing bundled and make another repo with similar name where I push in production mode so I can host the app and on the other app which is not bundled I can put a link to the hosted version so that way people can see the source code and the live version but that means some duplicate repositories.